# Smarty, new row every 4 iteration

Tags: php, foreach, html-table, smarty, counter

How can I set in Smarty that every 4 iteration in loop, I'll get new row in table?
I'm trying something like this:

```
<table>
    {foreach $arr as $v}
       {counter start=0}
       {if $counter/4 == 0}
           <tr><td>{$v}</td></tr>
       {else}
           <td>{$v}</td>
       {/if}
       <td>
    {/foreach}
</table>
```

But I understand it's idiotic, I'm stuck, is there a normal way to do that?

Comment: try `$counter % 4 == 0` because `$counter/4` is dividing operator. so it will not give you zero. to check divisibility always use `%`

Comment: do you want to add a row after every four cell is added ?

Comment: Yes, every four cell new row. like 

OOOO


OOOO


OOOO

but every 'OOOO' on new line.

Answer (score 5):

If you can live with an empty row if there is no data, then use this:

```
{assign var="counter" value="0"}
<table>
    <tr>
    {foreach $arr as $v}
       {assign var="counter" value=$counter + 1}
       {if $counter % 4 == 0}
           </tr><tr>
       {/if}
       <td>{$v}</td>
    {/foreach}
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you can't live with this, then you need to check if there is data available before rendering the table.

It remains to say that the count of `$arr` must be a multiple of `4`. Otherwise a `columnspan` attribute is required to be set properly.

Comment: you should probably use modulo %, not divide /

Comment: yeah, of course. Completely missed to replace that :)

Comment: +1 you are very faster than me. i was typing to post this solution.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not work, i get errors that type `Undefined index: counter in`, i wrote `$counter / 4` just for example, i dont know is it possible to check that way.

Comment: With assign now works, thanks, but they wrote `</tr><tr>` after each line, they didnt check `$counter % 4 == 0`

Comment: Nice, all okay, its work, thanks !
Just need to replace `value=$counter++` to `value=$counter + 1`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a Smarty 3 solution for any number of columns, without empty rows and adding a last empty cell with a colspan value if necessary:

```
   <table>
        <tr>
    {$cols=4}
    {foreach $arr as $v}
        <td>{$v}</td>
        {if !$v@last AND $v@iteration is div by $cols}
            </tr><tr>
        {/if}
        {if $v@last AND $v@iteration is not div by $cols}
            <td colspan="{$cols-$v@iteration%$cols}"></td>
        {/if}
     {foreachelse}
           <td colspan="{$cols}">No data</td>    
     {/foreach}
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach without an aditional counter variable and no empty row

```
<table>
<tr>
    {foreach from=$aArray item=sValue name=tags_foreach}
    {if $smarty.foreach.tags_foreach.index != 0 AND $smarty.foreach.tags_foreach.index mod 4 == 0}
        </tr><tr>
    {/if}

    <td>
        {$sValue}
    </td>
    {/foreach}
</tr>
```